# Printf and sleep inside for loop?

Tags: c, linux, sleep

I can't understand why following code works like this..I mean: instead of printing "hello" after each one second delay...it wait 5 second and display *`hellohellohellohellohello`* at once.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
   printf("hello");
   sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: You need to flush standard output somehow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: You did not include your code in a `main` function... Did you really compile and execute that?

Answer (score 12):

The output of `printf()` (`stdout`) is line buffered by default if the output is going to a tty. You need one of

```
printf("hello\n");
```

or

```
printf("hello");
fflush(stdout);
```

The latter will explicitly flush the output each iteration.

Answer (score 4):

printf do not print immediatly, instead it cache it line per line.

Add "\n" (newline) add the end of your string `printf("hello\n");` or use write function instead `write(STDOUT_FILENO, "hello", sizeof("hello"));`.

Answer (score 3):

You are writing to standard output (`stdout`), which is *buffered*. If you want the content to be immediately printed, you may flush the output or insert a newline.

You can add a `\n` to the end of your string so as to print the newline -- change your `printf` line to:

```
   printf("hello\n");
```

For flushing the `stdout` buffer call `fflush` on it, after the `printf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
       printf("hello");
       fflush(stdout);
       sleep(1);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general the output can be buffered. That means the implementation collects several bytes before actually writing to the console. You can explicitly write the buffer by fflush(stdout). This is true for all file descriptors, one of which is stdout, the terminal output. You can disable the buffering with setbuff(stdout, NULL), but this is almost never a good idea performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
printf("hello\n");
i=0;
sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a comment explaining why this will solve the problem.

Comment: i=0; to block writing "Hello" 5 times .

Comment: This won't have the intended effect. It causes the loop to run forever (and keep printing "Hello" while doing so). The OP still wants to have it print "Hello" five times, but having a delay between each.