# Moving the cursor and printing characters in console doesn't work with sleep

Tags: c, linux, unix, terminal

I want to print a sequence of characters one by one in the same place. I print one letter, then wait 1 second with sleep, move cursor one column left using console code, print next letter and so on. The problem is as a result program waits the sum of all sleeps (2s in my example) and then prints only the last character ('y'). Same goes with nanosleep, waiting for a signal instead of sleeping. How to make it work?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf( "H" );
    sleep( 1 );
    printf( "\033[1D" );
    printf( "e" );
    sleep( 1 );
    printf( "\033[1D" );
    printf( "y" );
}
```

Comment: buffering, use `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf()` (or at least before each `sleep()`)

Comment: If `fflush()` looks too clumsy, you can also `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` before the first `printf()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does printf() not print anything before sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/338273/608639), [Printf and sleep inside for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25627535/608639) and friends. Also see [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/608639)

Answer (score 5):

Output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is by default (when connected to a terminal) *line buffered*. That means output is flushed (actually written to the terminal) either when the buffer is full, when you print a newline, or when you explicitly flush it (with [`fflush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush)).

In your case, since you never fill the buffer and don't print newlines, you need to explicitly call `fflush(stdout)` before each call to `sleep`.

Comment: Thank you for further explanation :)